# How to code for scanning fingerprint in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android

I am designing an Android application in which I need to identify user's fingerprints. But this functionality is only offered in Android 6.0 marshmallow. I want to make this functionality work in android 5.1.1 device having an inbuilt fingerprint scanner. Does anybody have any idea that how I can do this?

Comment: Contact the device manufacturer and ask them. Any fingerprint APIs will be tied to the hardware, and will be hardware-specific.

Comment: I have a one plus 2 android phone & it has Inbulit fingerprint scanner in it.But It has android 5.1.1 version that doesnt support the fingerprint scanning for its applications.

Comment: So my application is not working in that device. There are no SDK available to perform this?? @CommonsWare

Comment: I have no idea. I am not the manufacturer of that device. **Contact the device manufacturer and ask them**.